# How to find avg in crossfilter group in most efficient way

Tags: javascript

I want to find the average in the data by grouping similar things in the data.

For example I have data in an object like this:

```
var data = [
        { key: 'A', value: 1 },
        { key: 'A', value: 6 },
        { key: 'B', value: 8 },
        { key: 'B', value: 9 },
        { key: 'A', value: 7 },
        { key: 'A', value: 6 },
        { key: 'C', value: 8 },
        { key: 'A', value: 9 }
    ];
```

How do I find average key-wise without recalculating the average at each step (because I don't know the count at once)?

If I want it in one iteration what is the best way?

Comment: You could use Array.prototype.reduce method to get the sum of all keys in an array. [Reduce Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table for the result object and for additional information, like `sum` and `count`.

In every loop update the result set with new values and the average.

```js
var data = [{ key: 'A', value: 1 }, { key: 'A', value: 6 }, { key: 'B', value: 8 }, { key: 'B', value: 9 }, { key: 'A', value: 7 }, { key: 'A', value: 6 }, { key: 'C', value: 8 }, { key: 'A', value: 9 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];
    
data.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!hash[o.key]) {
        hash[o.key] = { _: { key: o.key, avg: 0 }, sum: 0, count: 0 };
        result.push(hash[o.key]._);
    }
    hash[o.key].sum += o.value;
    hash[o.key].count++;
    hash[o.key]._.avg = hash[o.key].sum / hash[o.key].count;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```